# Counterexample for a.s. convergent series in Probability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Can anyone give a counterexample to prove the following statement?

The existence of a further a.s. convergent subsequence of $(_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ 's every subsequence, do not imply a.s convergence of $(_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$.

While there is no equivalence for a.s. convergence, there are for convergence in probability or $L^p$.

Comment: There is a so called subsubsequence lemma that says that if you can take a converging subsequence from every subsequence of the original sequence, then the original sequence converges. Is that what you are looking for ? Or are you saying that this result is not valid for a.s. convergence ?

Comment: @Gâteau-Gallois this result is not valid for a.s. convergence, so I want a counter example.

Comment: Just take any sequence which converges in probability but not almost surely.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose Y is a uniform distribution on $\Omega=[0,1]$. 
We note $S_n=\sum_{i=2}^{n}\frac{1}{i}$.

$A_n=[S_n mod 1,S_{n+1} mod 1]$ if $S_n mod 1<S_{n+1} mod 1$

or

$A_n=[S_n mod 1,1]\cup [0,S_{n+1} mod 1]$ if $S_n mod 1>S_{n+1} mod 1$

We define $X_n=1-(1-\frac{1}{n})\chi_{A_n}$.

We find that $X_n$ converge in probability to 1, while it does not converge a.s. to 1. Since with measure 1, $X_n(\omega)$ do not converge.

Answer (score 0):

If a sequence converges in probability then any subsequence has a further subsequence which is a.s. convergent. But there are simple examples of sequences which converge in probability but not a.s. One can be obtained by linearly indexing the "moving block", given by $X_{n,k}(\omega)=\begin{cases} 1 & \omega \in [k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n}] \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$,where $n=1,2,\dots$ and $k=0,1,\dots,2^n-1$, and the underlying probability space is $[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure.